# Organizing a pure-C project so it can be built using GUI tools on different platforms

Tags: c, linux, macos

I am planning to start updating some old-ish C code to C99, hosted publicly on GitHub. The code compiles without a single change on Linux, macOS and Windows.

To ease poking about in the code, on my Mac I used an Xcode project file to organize it. I believe other users might find this useful too, and on .Net as well.

So, my question is purely organizational - does anyone out there have a canonical example of how to arrange such a project physically? That is, a widely used example that has Mac, Win and Linux builds using platform specific project files *and* `make`/`make config`

I know can just put the project files in subfolders, but I want to be sure that if there is a "standard" way to do this that I use it too.

Comment: Maybe, consider Cmake ?

Comment: CMake does not make native project files, AFAIK.